# libtool installed but not found in /usr/bin

Tags: linux, bash

I have to compile a program (not made by myself) and in his `autogen.sh` there is a script command that search *libtool*

`LIBTOOL=$(which libtool)`

but the command don't find the command. I see the path for libtool is `/usr/share/libtool` instead `/usr/bin/libtool`.

I locate *libtoolize* in `/usr/bin/`, but I did not change any path.

I'd like to know if there is difference between *libtool* and *libtoolize*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same thing, libtoolize is part of libtool.

From this link (http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Invoking-libtoolize.html):

> The libtoolize program provides a standard way to add libtool support
>   to your package. In the future, it may implement better usage
>   checking, or other features to make libtool even easier to use.

Comment: I solved changed `LIBTOOL=$(which libtool)` with `LIBTOOL=$(which libtoolize)`.
Yes I've read the articles, but the question is: now this is the standard?

Comment: If it is the standard of using libtool then the documentation is in need of an update. I tend to think it's more likely to be a matter of how the program you're working on is attempting to use libtool (maybe outdated - from an earlier libtool version maybe?).

Answer (score 58):

I ran into this same problem today on a Debian system and (eventually) discovered that though the `libtool` package was installed, the `libtool-bin` package was not.

```
apt-get install libtool-bin
```

Problem solved: `which libtool` prints `/usr/bin/libtool`.

Comment: Thank you! (I am sure the package-maker _"only wanted to help"_ via not putting libtool into package libtool.)